# Leitura de array com php

Tags: php, array

boa tarde, tenho este array que vem de variaveis $form

```
Array
(
    [nome] => 765hygfy
    [data_nascimento] => ftyftyf
    [email] => tyfytf@jhff.com
    [sexo] => Feminino
    [rg] => ytfytfyt
    [cpf] => fytfty
    [telefone_residencial] => fty
    [telefone_celular] => fyt
    [telefone_recado] => 
    [cep] => fytf
    [estado] => MS
    [cidade] => fytfytf
    [bairro] => ytf
    [logradouro_rua] => ftyf
    [numero] => tyfyt
    [complemento] => fty
    [referencia] => fytf
    [onde_conheceu] => FaceBook
    [revendeu_outras_marcas] => Não
    [quais] => ytftyf
    [horario_de_contato] => Manhã
)
```

eles estão vindo de um formulário como a names neste padrao

```
form[nome]
form[email]
```

e assim vai

o que preciso fazer é o php ler este array printando o key depois o value
já fiz vários foreach ate um for e volta em branco.

meu foreach

```
foreach($_POST['form'] as $key => $value){ 
  $nome = arrumanome($key);
  $msg.= $nome.": ".$value."<br>";
}
```

ele volta so isso aki

```
:
:
:
:
:
:
:
:
```

Comment: Como assim volta em branco? como ficou a estrutura do foreach?

Comment: editei com o meu foreach e o q volta

Comment: Dessa forma, seria melhor fazer 2 `foreach`: um só com `$_POST` e o interno com o `$value`

Comment: pode colocar o código html também?

Comment: Tira o `['form']` do `$_POST` do `foreach` e veja o que retorna.

Comment: olha fiz um var_dump do $_POST e ele retorna todas variaveis e var_dump de $_POST['form'] e volta o array certinho como coloquei na msg la em cima mas o foreach nao ta printando o key nem o value.

Comment: Verifique o console do navegador e veja se seu servidor não está fazendo reload da página.

Comment: Como está a parte HTML? Seria Ajax ou Form normal? Ou a chamada está sendo feita via WebService?

Answer (score 0):

Rapaz, parece que vc enviou o formulário em branco ou que **sua função arrumanome está modificando seus dados** e deixando eles em branco.

Veja se te ajuda o código abaixo, que funciona apropriadamente:

**Um form html com alguns dos seus dados para testar:**

```
<form action="foreach.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="form[nome]" value="Nome Teste"><br>
    <input type="text" name="form[data_nascimento]" value="31/01/1980"><br>
    <input type="text" name="form[email]" value="teste@dominio.com"><br>
    <input type="text" name="form[sexo]" value="Masculino"><br>
    <input type="text" name="form[rg]" value="123456789"><br>
    <input type="text" name="form[cpf]" value="1198765432"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">

</form>
```

**foreach.php**

```
<?php

$dados_post = $_POST["form"];

$msg='';

foreach($dados_post as $key => $value)
{
    $msg.= $key . ": " . $value . "<br>";
}

echo $msg;
```

Resultado na tela:

```
nome: Nome Teste
data_nascimento: 31/01/1980
email: teste@dominio.com
sexo: Masculino
rg: 123456789
cpf: 1198765432
```

Comment: ctz q he algono meu apache coiei e colei o cod aki e continua em branco

Comment: Pode ser no navegador tb. Olha o código fonte da página pra ver se tem algo estranho.